# Why does the guarded statements not run?

Tags: haskell

Hello I'm in a programming languages class which we were just introduced to Haskell. So in the homework we had to create a function that can remove multiple instances of an element in a list. I had a previous function that can remove one element but my removeMultipleElements does not want to run the guarded statements and just go straight to the empty list. Any help is appreciated. I'm sure it is something syntactical but I'm not sure what.

Here is the code

```
--This one works great    
removeElement x aList@(y:ys)
        | y == x = rest
        | otherwise = y : rest
          where
            rest = removeElement x ys 
    removeElement _ _ = []

--this does not want to
removeMultipleElements remove@(y:ys) aList@(x:xs) 
        | elem y aList = removeMultipleElements ys (removeElement y aList)
        | not (elem y aList) = removeMultipleElements ys aList
        | otherwise = aList
removeMultipleElements _ _ = []
```

Comment: Please make sure to get the indentation right when posting StackOverflow questions (you can paste Haskell code as it is, then mark all the code and just press `ctrl`+`k` to achieve this). Also, please always add type signatures!

Comment: edited :) it was my understanding that the type inference already assumes what I want to do. Both return lists.

Comment: @KevinD I wouldn't suggest making that assumption... It can lead to weirder looking type errors. If you specify what you want the types of the top level bindings to be, the errors much clearer (because you are telling the type checker what you want it to attempt to match against). Top-level type signatures also make the code easier to read.

Comment: By the way, your call to elem, which you probably inserted to save the time of traversing the list with an element that's not in it, will take as much time as traversing the list with that element would have, because that's exactly what elem does. You can just tell it to remove y and if it's not in there then nothing happens.

Comment: Style comment: the `otherwise` branch looks funny. You check for a condition and its negation, so there are no other cases. I'd change the `not (elem y aList)` to `otherwise` and remove the third guard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the guard, it is that

```
removeMultipleElements remove@(y:ys) aList@(x:xs)
```

will only match when neither list is empty, so in your base case you have

```
removeMultipleElements [] aList
```

which matches only with the second definition and so becomes the empty list.  You should probably replace

```
removeMultipleElements _ _ = []
```

with something like

```
removeMultipleElements _ xs = xs
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much for your help. This really opened my eyes to Haskell!